# Global Address Book Has Different Entries from Earlier

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013, outlook-2010

We have an Exchange 2013 server running, and it appears as though earlier today, everyone from AD was showing up in the GAL  (All new users).  Now, there are only about half of those users, plus users that I had previously deleted from AD showing up in Outlook 2010 for multiple users.  I am not even sure where to look to even start reviewing any issues, and I am wondering if anyone has seen this before.  It's pulling the GAL down, but only a cached copy from earlier today, it seems.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Title error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking the Global Address List, Offline Address Book, or the list as seen from webmail on the Client Access Server?

**GAL Updates**

The actual GAL (Global Address List) should update immediately upon user creation in Active Directory, but may require replication across domain controllers.

Force a GAL update with PoSh:

```
Get-GlobalAddressList | Update-GlobalAddressList
```

**OAB Updates**

The OAB (Offline Address Book) is updated every 24 hours by default on the Exchange server, configurable through the Organization Configuration.

Force an OAB update with PoSh:

```
Get-OfflineAddressBook | Update-OfflineAddressBook
```

**OAB -> CAS**

The replication of the OAB to the CAS (Client Access Server) can take up to eight hours after the last update.

Force OAB-CAS replication with PoSh:

```
Get-ClientAccessServer | Update-FileDistributionService
```

**Outlook OAB Download**

The download of the OAB by cached Outlook clients from the CAS happens at most every 24 hours.

You can force an OAB download in Outlook through Send-Receive settings.

The disconnect is probably somewhere along those lines. If you don't want to go down the line forcing updates, just wait 24 hours and see if you still see issues.

Comment: Thank you Hyppy for your reply.  I am concerned about the OAB I guess.  The client computers using Outlook 2010 had everything correct earlier today in the address book.  It was synced with AD perfectly.  Now, just a couple of hours later, all of the clients are pulling down an "old" version of the address book, which includes previously deleted AD users and only half of the new users that were created.  I will give the Get-OfflineAddressBook | Update-OfflineAddressBook a shot and see if that works.